# Need help redirecting a specific URL

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, rss

I've been trying to .htaccess redirect a specific URL in WordPress with no luck. Here's what I'm trying to accomplish:

/feed and /feed/ should redirect to FeedBurner

BUT any feed URL that has /feed/?... should NOT redirect

Everything I've tried redirects EVERYTHING with /feed (including /feed/?) in it to FeedBurner.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteRule ^feed/?$ http://path/to/feedburner
```

Should work. Can you show what you've tried?

Comment: Doesn't seem to work -- not redirecting. I'll try to dig up the code I was trying (it was a few days ago).